# Set an SSIS SQL Agent job to unexpected error or failure

Tags: ssis, jobs, ssis-2014

I was running a series of SSIS packages in a SQL Agent job on a virtual server when the server was shutdown - hard.

The package execution report shows it as still running even though I believe it is not. I believe this is because the Agent was not able to write whatever end state record which was required for it to show as "Unexpected termination".

1. How do I verify that it is, in fact, not still running?
2. How do I tell the SSIS Reports > All executions that it is not running?

Can I update or insert a record into an SSISdb table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trace the query the report is generating you'll see that the executions are stored in the `[catalog].[executions]` of the database behind the Integration Services Catalog.

You can just modify your `[end_time]` there and you should be able to 'fix' the report.

I haven't managed to reproduce your exact scenario (i.e. hard resetting a VM to get a package in the running state) but I could modify the value in that field and the All Executions report reflects the new values.

However, don't set the `end_time` too much behind the `start_time` as you'll get overflow errors in the report if your package appears to have run for days.

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878089.aspx) you have these statuses available to you:

> The status of the operation. The possible values are created (1),
>   running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended unexpectedly
>   (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9).

So running this:

```
UPDATE [catalog].[executions]
SET [end_time] = DATEADD(minute, 2, start_time)
    ,[status] = 6
WHERE [execution_id] = 2;
```

on my system results in a package that shows "unexpected termination" after 2 minutes.